# Merge two map with different type to one map

Tags: java

I have two map from different type:

```
class Type3{
  Type1 type1;
  Type2 type2;

// getters and setters...

}


Map<Integer,Type1> map1;
Map<Integer,Type2> map2;
```

I want to merge them to one map by same key.
like his:
`Map<Integer,Type3> map3 = // merege map1,map2.`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `Stream`s:

```
Map<Integer,Type3> output =
    map1.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                  e -> new Type3(e.getValue(),map2.get(e.getKey()))));
```

Assuming `Type3` has a constructor that accepts a `Type1` instance and a `Type2` instance.

Note that the output `Map` will contain only keys that appear in the first `Map` (`map1`).

If both of the input `Map`s may have keys not present in the other map, it would be better to stream over the union of the key sets of both `Map`s, in order not to skip any keys:

```
Set<Integer> allKeys = new HashSet<> (map1.keySet());
allKeys.addAll(map2.keySet());
Map<Integer,Type3> output =
    allKeys.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                     key -> new Type3(map1.get(key),map2.get(key))));
```

Comment: Thanks by this solution have a problem - what about the case of map2 have key that doesn't exist in map1 - the entry will not create.

Comment: @user1137582 that's true. If map1 may have keys not in map2 and vica versa, perhaps it would be better to stream over the union of the keySets of the 2 maps.

Answer (score 1):

> If Type1 and Type2 inherits the same Parent, you can re-initialise your Map with the following:

```
Map<Integer,IType> mapCommon;
```

> IType would be like a dummy class: Define an interface

```
interface IType {

}
//Program Type1 & Type2 to be like this

class Type1 implements IType{..}

class Type2 implements IType{..}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for more straightforward solution.